# Link a UILabel and a UIButton in IB

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

During a time in my app - I make a button a button not enabled

```
myButton.enabled = NO;
```

The problem is that I've made my button in IB with an image, and just a UILabel overtop of it.
The label does not grey out when the buttons does.

In IB - is there a way to link the label to the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without you doing the linking action yourself, as @Eiko rightly pointed out.

It sounds like you need to make your image the *background*-image of the button, so you can have your label as the button text, *like it is intended to be used*. Then you can specify colors, fonts & images for all 4 possible states.

If you decide to invent the wheel yourself, by keeping button and label as separate objects, you will have to invent everything around it as well.

Comment: I've made the image a backround image and used the title as the text.
Much appreciated. Thank-you.

Answer (score -2):

You can add another outlet in your code, i.e. `IBOutlet UILabel *yourLabel;`

Then link this outlet to your label, same procedure as linking the button.

Comment: I see what you mean - But I do know if I've made myself understood.

I want the label 'linked' with the button, 

so in the code when I call 

    myButton.enabled = NO;
 
The label AND the button both become greyed out.

Comment: Downvoting after a year... I think I can at least expect a comment. There is nothing wrong with this answer.